# Creating groups with common relationships out of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, grouping

I have a dataset that must be organized in a particular way for another team to input into an application.

My dataset looks like this:

```
XX  AAA
XX  BBB
XX  CCC
XX  DDD
XX  EEE
XX  FFF
YY  AAA
YY  BBB
YY  CCC
YY  DDD
YY  EEE
YY  FFF
ZZ  AAA
ZZ  BBB
LL  CCC
JJ  DDD
```

I need the output to look something like this:

```
XX, YY: AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF #this is the most important "grouping." 
ZZ: AAA, BBB 
LL: CCC
JJ: DDD
```

The most important relationship is the first line in which there are multiple "keys" associated with multiple "values." The crucial details is that the "keys" share all of the same "values."

I realize I am using dictionary terms but I have yet to find a way to organize a dictionary in this manner.

So far I've tried for loops, placing the data in dictionaries with keys and values but the problem is that I need to associate multiple keys with multiple values and I haven't found a way to do that.
Really need some help here.

Comment: just to clarify, my dataset is a dataframe, i realize it does not look like one above.

Comment: Hi there, it's generally expected to include a minimal, reproducible example, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Noted and will do so in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your DF is such as

```
   col1 col2
0    XX  AAA
1    XX  BBB
2    XX  CCC
3    XX  DDD
4    XX  EEE
5    XX  FFF  ... and so on using your data
```

then the code below groups on col1 and combines col2 values, then collects duplicates combinations using another grouping. A frozenset because that is hashable (so groupable). :

```
df2 = df.groupby('col1').agg(frozenset).reset_index()
df2 = df2.groupby('col2')['col1'].agg(set).reset_index()
d = {}
for row in df2.itertuples():
    d[",".join(row.col1)] = list(row.col2)
    
print(d)
```

will give for `d`

```
{'JJ': ['DDD'], 'LL': ['CCC'], 'ZZ': ['AAA', 'BBB'], 'YY,XX': ['DDD', 'CCC', 'BBB', 'FFF', 'AAA', 'EEE']}
```

The intermediary DFs are shown below to make the process clearer.

```
  col1                            col2
0   JJ                           (DDD)
1   LL                           (CCC)
2   XX  (AAA, DDD, EEE, BBB, FFF, CCC)
3   YY  (AAA, DDD, EEE, BBB, FFF, CCC)
4   ZZ                      (AAA, BBB)

                             col2      col1
0                           (DDD)      {JJ}
1                           (CCC)      {LL}
2                      (AAA, BBB)      {ZZ}
3  (AAA, DDD, EEE, BBB, FFF, CCC)  {YY, XX}
```

Comment: Awesome and thank you. The one exception to the output you shared is that I need the keys XX and YY to be grouped together with the values AAA, etc. That's what I can't seem to do.

Comment: See edited answer which I think now meets your clarified requirement.

Comment: This is incredible. Thank you SO MUCH! Really do appreciate this.